# Refresh Tabbar (Label of Tabbar Icon)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uilabel, uitabbar

i switch the labelname of the first tabbaricon like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

   NSString *temp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
    if ([temp isEqualToString:@"OFF"]) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TabButtonOFF", nil);
    }
    else {

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TabButton1", nil);

    }
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];


}
return self;
}
```

it works fine by start and stop the app, but is there a way to refresh (reload) the labelname?
to runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change tab name in uitabbarcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250413/change-tab-name-in-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: i want to reload the new title! i know how to set them.