# How to give name to TabBarController items, if the ViewControllers it refer are NavigationControllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

According to the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250413/change-tab-name-in-uitabbarcontroller), I need to set title to each of the ViewControllers that's referred in the TabBarController. Yes, I understand that. But when I use NavigationController, I can't seem to change the items' title even though I have set the title of both the NavigationController and the RootViewController of the NavigationController to 'Connections' in the screen shot.

[image: Interface Builder Screenshot]

The result in the TabBarController is just Item 1, Item 2, and Item 3, not Connections, Org, and Chats, as I expected.

What did I do wrong? How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: but tabbarviewcontroller already give navigation bar so than why you want navigation controller

Comment: You can try adding a UITabBarItem from the Object Library to the UITabBarController. From there you can add a title and image as you need.

Comment: @DarjiJigar I want to create same structure like facebook app for iOS.

Comment: @rach sorry, the tabbar of the UITabBarItem is uneditable (e.g. I can't drag and place any UITabBarItem from the Object Library to the tabbar).

Comment: Hold on. I seem to have misunderstood your question. You wanted the tab bar items to have a title right? As in, from the screen caps you posted in your questions, there are dark grey areas on the bottom of your Connection,Org & Chat NavigationControllers. You want them to have an title right? Just to wrap my head around this question.

Comment: Actually my previous answer was a little off. I meant to ask you to drag a UITabBarItem to your NavigationControllers on the Storyboard and then set their title from there.

Comment: @rach ooooh! It's working! That was an unintuitive way of Apple to design the Interface Builder. -_- anyway, you should make it an answer, so I can choose it as a correct answer!

Comment: Sure. I shall work on it and include some image captures so as to help others who might run into the same problem. But yes, I agree. Some things in XCode can be counter-intuitive but it is much easier nowadays compared to the earlier versions. :)

Comment: @rach nice! I shall await for the full answer! :D

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to explain your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work around this issue, the quickest and most direct way of solving this is via the storyboard. With the structure posted by question, you can simple drag a `UITabBarItem` to the NavigationController (not the UITabBarController) and XCode you should be able to customise the TabBarItems with titles and images. It should look something like this:

[image: TabBarItem title]

Answer (score 0):

To set title of a view controller from storyboard

- Select a view controller.
- Double tap a on navigation bar that is appeared after setting root view controller.
- And finally set your desired title.

Other way is just select a view controller for which you wish to change title after that select navigation bar, go to Attribute Inspector and set title.

Comment: The problem is that I have clicked on the Navigation Controller (not View Controller), and then I tried to double tap (or select) the navigation bar of that Navigation Controller, but I can't select it so I can set the desired title on the Attribute Inspector. This is Navigation Controller we're talking about, not View Controller.