# Swift Tabbar Controller not displaying Items

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Ok so i dragged a Swift Tab Bar Controller, and I would like to edit the icons and the names of the bar items but they are not being displayed in my storyboard.

Comment: show the screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: Your initial storyboard might not be the one you are wanting it to be. A pic of the storyboard will surely help

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250413/change-tab-name-in-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take Tabbarcontroller and viewcontrollers that you want to add as a tab to storyboard.

than you need to create segue from tabcontroller to viewcontroller having relationship as ViewController.

Than Tab will appear to each of viewcontollers.

Hope this will solve your confusion.

Comment: Ok thank you, I knew to do that but I didn't want to go through the hastle